# Facebook OAuth and the PHP SDK... errors

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I'm working with Facebook login on my website and was looking at this example: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

When I hit "Login with Facebook" on the example site, I get an error:

```
An error occurred with PHP SDK Unit Tests. Please try again later.
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

I've tried it with their Javascript version and get an almost identical error (error with Mu Console...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't verified this myself but on their issue tracker there seems to be a similar, closed issue. https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/236

Whether this was closed as resolved or not isn't obvious from the description unfortunately.

Comment: @Dan: Good link, thank you... I still cant seem to get it to work though. It may have something to do with being already logged in/out, but that doesn't seem to change anything. Many upboats to you (if you notice your rep now!) for being the only one to give me an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have googled some more and without trying to get it working myself I was wondering what you downloaded from git. Did it include the tests?

Comment: @Dan: I downloaded the [example.php](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) from github as well as all the (relevant src files)[https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/src]. I haven't run any of the test stuff.

Comment: Browsing the Facebook Developers forums I found another post which doesn't help resolving the problem but makes me think that probably the example.php or a bit more of the release is causing the problem. Have you tried out their prior releases?

Comment: @Dan Certainly a good idea.... how do I get a hold of those previous versions? Does github have them?

Comment: Yes. Go to their project page and click the Downloads button. The window that pops up then should allow you to download older packages.

Comment: @Dan I tried downloading 2.1.2... I don't think it's quite that simple. The certificate I downloaded with the latest version doesn't support the earlier version, so when I try to use the earlier version, I get an error regarding the certificate.

Comment: @Tory Waterman Ah, makes sense. Unforunately I haven't done any facebook development myself so I don't know what else could be the problem. Is there an online example anywhere where I can have a look at it?

Comment: @Dan: Unfortunately everything I have is hosted locally so far. Other than the examples provided via github there's no real difference between my code and theirs.

Comment: Doesn't the URL get passed along to facebook? Is it possible that the domain is being matched with the app key and secret key and thus producing the problem when hosted locally. Otherwise I'm out of ideas I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dan: Actually, you're right. When run via my website, it seems to work... I'm just confused as to why their example which they provide doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the error. 
My solution was very simple. I've just check the app id and the other keys and I notice that they were bad. I have copied directly thes ones of the examples and this is why it didn't work.
Please, do just check again all the keys and be sure that they are ok.
I have used sdk 3.0.1, the last one it the time of writing this.